# SUM, COUNT with LEFT JOIN?

Tags: mysql

How can i get right sum and count with LEFT JOIN?

Now rows sum from both tables..

Is it possible to do without subquery?

```
SELECT 
    t1.Continent, t1.Region, 
    COUNT( t1.Region ) AS cRegion, t1.LifeExpectancy, 
    SUM( t1.Population ) AS sPopulation, SUM( t2.CountryCode ) AS cCities
    FROM Country AS t1
    LEFT JOIN City AS t2 ON t1.Code = t2.CountryCode
    GROUP BY t1.Region
    ORDER BY t1.Continent ASC
```

**City Table**
[image]

**Country Table**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't make any sense.  But if you join together the `City` and `Country` table, and group by the region, then you can compute the following stats for each region:

- number of cities per region
- number of countries per region
- total population per region

```
SELECT t1.Region,
       COUNT(*) AS cityCount,
       COUNT(DISTINCT t1.code) AS countryCount,
       SUM(t2.Population) AS regionPop
FROM Country t1
LEFT JOIN City t2
    ON t1.Code = t2.CountryCode
GROUP BY t1.Region
```

Comment: What is the exact problem?